# I want to run a small scale free-of-charge SFTP server among my friends. I want to run it from my Pi Zero on which I have Raspbian installed

Tags: permissions, ftp, sftp, username, open-source

I have searched for line command installation of ftp server. I installed a ftp file system with sudo apt-get install vsftpd. I were able to access it from a remote desktop computer using WinSCP. When I tried to add users using the "mkdir" command, I just get a message that I do not have permission. I have tried by enabling the ssh settings as well, but do not get any futher.
How do I add more users, each with their own password in line command? Is there another open source program which I can try to run a SFTP server from?
I have done some more reading on Kali Linux and then use APACHe, but if I can save some time on trail and error practice, it would be great.

Comment: Add users using `sudo adduser ` Also : it is not clear that you have installed a SSH server.

Comment: Neither Raspbian nor Kali is Ubuntu, sorry.